# Line-height issues when inline checkbox or radiobox is preceded by text

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using Bootstrap 3, I'm trying to create a form with a checkbox in the middle of a sentence. I'm assuming I should be using [Inline Checkboxes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-controls), but it does the following to my line-height:

[image]

Sample code is at http://www.bootply.com/92125.

Is there a way to get a checkbox truly inline with its surroundings?

Comment: I just tried your code, using Chrome. It worked perfectly inline. So, which browser you are using?

Comment: I've tested in current Firefox and Chrome, same issue in both. The full path in my code is: body > div.container > form.form-horizontal > div.page-header > p > label.checkbox-inline > input

Comment: Please edit your question by putting the full version code. So that I can test for you.

Comment: I've revised the question to link to the code snippet at http://www.bootply.com/92125

Answer (score 0):

I have rechecked your code on the Bootply. The problem occurred when the `form-horizontal` class is used. I don't know why you need to use it, you may have some reasons.

Let's take a look at the `Bootstrap.css` on the line 2153:

```
.form-horizontal .control-label,
.form-horizontal .radio,
.form-horizontal .checkbox,
.form-horizontal .radio-inline,
.form-horizontal .checkbox-inline {
  padding-top: 7px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

You can see that there is the `padding-top: 7px`. This will push your checkbox down `7px`.

---

In order to solve this issue, you have two options.

1. Delete the `form-horizontal` class, if it isn't necessary for you.
2. Create a new class and set the `padding-top: 0` :

Your CSS file :

```
.foo{
  padding-top: 0 !important;
}
```

Your HTML file :

```
<label class="checkbox-inline foo"><input type="checkbox" value="Adopted" id="family-adopted">please check this box.</label>
```